# Can't use socialite on lumen 5.2

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-socialite, lumen-5.2

Here is my config socialite for lumen but I got error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on null

Any idea?

---

my AuthController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Socialite;

class AuthController extends Controller {

public function redirectToProvider() {
  return Socialite :: driver('github')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback() {
  $user = Socialite :: driver('github')->user();
  dd( $user );
}
}
```

my Route.php

```
$app->get('auth/github', 'AuthController@redirectToProvider');
$app->get('auth/github/callback', 'AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

my bootstrap/app.php
added this

```
class_alias(Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class, 'Socialite');
$app->register(Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class);
$app->configure('services');
```

my config/services

```
 return [
   'github' => [
    'client_id' => '############',
    'client_secret' => '#############',
    'redirect' => 'my callback url',
  ],
];
```

---

**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function set() on null in D:\xampp\htdocs\user-service\vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\AbstractProvider.php on line 134
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1
FatalErrorException in D:\xampp\htdocs\user-service\vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\AbstractProvider.php line 134:
Call to a member function set() on null
in AbstractProvider.php line 134
at Application->handleShutdown() in RegistersExceptionHandlers.php line 55
at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}()
```

**

Comment: Can you please post the complete error message with files and lines?

Comment: posted complete error!

Comment: I think It's relate to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class

Comment: What makes you think it is related to `StartSession::class`?

Comment: Because on lumen 5.1 it's work! and it's related to StartSession::class that used $app->middleware bootstrap/app

Comment: You are completly right. Session aren't supported/included anymore in Lumen 5.2. I updated my answer with the release notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to correct  your Socialite calls in your two methods:

```php
public function redirectToProvider()
{
  return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
  $user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();
  dd( $user );
}
```

Don't use spaces at `Socialite :: driver`.

**Important change Lumen 5.2** (see [release notes](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#5.2.0))

> Lumen 5.2 represents a shift on slimming Lumen to focus solely on serving stateless, JSON APIs. As such, sessions and views are no longer included with the framework.

Sessions are not supported anymore in Lumen 5.2. If you need those you better use Laravel instead.