# How can I use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class on lumen 5.2

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-middleware, lumen-5.2

I got this **Error:**

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 839:
Unresolvable dependency resolving 
[Parameter #0 [ <required> $app ]] in class Illuminate\Support\Manager
```

**bootstrap/app.php :**

```
$app->middleware([
 Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
]);
```

Comment: We need more info. What is your goal? What other classes did you create? When did this error occur?

Comment: this is releated to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235043/cant-use-socialite-on-lumen-5-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recap of what needs to be done to activate sessions in Lumen (tested on Lument 5.4):

**config/session.php**

Download session config from Laravel repo.

**bootstrap/app.php**

```
// Load session config (otherwise it won't be loaded)
$app->configure('session');

// Add `Session` middleware
$app->middleware(Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class);

// Add `SessionServiceProvider`
$app->register(Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class);

// fix `BindingResolutionException` problem
$app->bind(Illuminate\Session\SessionManager::class, function ($app) {    
    return $app->make('session');
});
```

After that you can access session with `app('session')` in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Before adding `StartSession` middleware, inject this dependency to container:

```
$app->bind(Illuminate\Session\SessionManager::class, function ($app) {
    return new Illuminate\Session\SessionManager($app);
});

$app->middleware([
    Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
]);
```